# React-Scroll-Parallax cropped image issue

Tags: reactjs, parallax

I'm trying to use [this package](https://github.com/jscottsmith/react-scroll-parallax#readme) to make a parallax on React

The parallax is working fine, but as you can [see on this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owv3P.png)...the pictures are cut out.

Here is the code :

```js
function ParallaxHeader() {
  return (
    <div className="header">
      <ParallaxProvider>
      <ParallaxBanner
        className="parallaxbanner"
        layers={[
            {
                image: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/782917695132794883/797039487518900224/parallax6.png',
                amount: 0,
                expanded: false,
            },
            {
                image: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/782917695132794883/797039486449614879/parallax5.png',
                amount: -0.5,
                expanded: false,
            },
            {
                image: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/782917695132794883/797039485795565598/parallax4.png',
                amount: -0.4,
                expanded: false,
            },
            {
                image: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/782917695132794883/797036547924819998/parallax3.png',
                amount: -0.1,
                expanded: false,

            },
            {
                image: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/782917695132794883/797036546376859668/parallax2.png',
                amount: -0.2,
                expanded: false,
            },
            {
                image: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/782917695132794883/797036545390936094/parallax1.png',
                amount: -0.3,
                expanded: false,
            },

        ]}
        style={{
            height: '500px',
            width: '100vw',
        }}
      >
    </ParallaxBanner>
    </ParallaxProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried adding the expanded: false but nothing happens. Changing the height in style grossly enlarges the picture out of proportions so it's not that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I am stuck with the same thing. Got a fix yet?